# Cannot open PDB file error in OpenCV running on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to open PDB file but it gives following errors:

```
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
```

it gives error in OpenCV running on Visual Studio 2010.
Please help me to tell, why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

These aren't really errors; they are informational in nature. Unless you have a reason to do Windows kernel debugging (i.e., you are doing driver development or something similar) you shouldn't worry about these messages. As long as you have debugging information for your program, you should be fine.

Make sure debugging information is enabled for your project like this:

1. Goto **Project Propeties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging**
2. Make sure **Generate Debug Info** is set to **Yes**